# How do I insert a partial view in a View at a certain place in the view with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pjax

I have an MVC3 application that I am implementing [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#readme) into .  Everything is working well except what to do on the server side when an address gets loaded that doesn't already have the main view on the client side.  My Controller code looks like

```
public virtual ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {
        var partDetail = new PartDetail(id);
        var partialView = PartialView("Details", partDetail);
        if(Request.Headers["X-PJAX"]!= null)
        {
            return partialView;
        }

        var mainView =  View("Index");
        // Stick Partial View into main view at #update_panel?
        return mainView;
    }
```

How can I stick the partial View into the main view so it inserts the partial view in the  #update_panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, without a major refactor, you could do the following.

(this assumes that you are able to set the `@model` on index.cshtml to `PartDetail()`).

in your controller action above, change:

```
var mainView =  View("Index");
```

to:

```
var mainView =  View("Index", partDetail);
```

then, inside your index.cshtml, add the following:

```
<div id="update_panel">@RenderPartial("Details", Model)</div>
```

As i said, this will ONLY work if the index @model is set to `PartDetail()`, otherwise, a little refactoring on the model in the index view will be required to include this `PartDetail()` model. this viewmodel might well look like the following:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    ModelForIndex Index{get; set;}
    PartDetail Details{get; set;}
}
```

this refactored viewmodel would be added to the index.cshtml as `@model IndexViewModel` and consumed by the partial as:

```
<div id="update_panel">@RenderPartial("Details", Model.Details)</div>
```

hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are doing there...I use the Index view as the container for several other partials as well.  Should I just do an model!=null statement?  This might work without major refactoring, but I'd have to flesh it out a bit.  What kind of 'major' refactoring would you suggest?

Comment: see amendment above - might work with minor tweaking (or not :-))

Comment: I'll start playing around with this after lunch, but I think it is a pretty decent way to go.